# How to translate Next, Cancel, Quit Buttons ? (Qt Installer Framework based)

Tags: qt, localization, qt5, qt-installer

I would like to translate my installer wizard (Qt Installer Framework based) in English or French (OS language depends).

I added those lines in the "installscript.qs" file :

```
Component.prototype.retranslateUi = function()
{
    component.languageChanged();
}
```

and I added those in "config.xml" file :

```
<Installer>
    ...
    <Translations>
        <Translation>fr.qm</Translation>
    </Translations>
</Installer>
```

But everything is ok (all long texts are translated) (in French) but the buttons like "Next", "Cancel", "Quit" are not translated (see the screenshot) :

[image]

ps: I don't want to use C++ code. (only Script or Xml)

Comment: Are you using an french or english OS?

Comment: I'm using a french OS :Windows 10 with french

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the Qt translation file in addition to your own .qm file(s). The file is located in the translation sub-folder of your Qt installation folder (e.g. `./usr/share/qt5/translations/`). For some languages it seems sufficient to load qt_xx (where XX should be replaced with your locale), but for German I had to load "qtbase_XX" to translate the Next and Cancel buttons. In example for the `fr` locale they are named `qt_fr.qm` and `qtbase_fr.qm`.

---

**EDIT:**

Because of the comment of John Smith I checked the Installer framework source and the framework is not capable loading more than one translation file:

See `installer-framework/src/libs/installer/component.cpp`

```
/*!
     Loads the translations matching the name filters \a qms inside \a directory. Only translations
    with a base name matching the current locale's name are loaded. For more information, see
    \l{Translating Pages}.
*/
void Component::loadTranslations(const QDir &directory, const QStringList &qms)
```

So my original answer above (which would lead to a translated `QWizard::CancelButton`) is not working.

I got the `Quit` button of the Installer Frameworks translation example translated to German by correcting the de.ts file provided within the framworks source in `installer-framework/src/sdk/translations`

The original translation coming with the feramework is missing an `&amp;`:

So, changing:

```
<context>
    <name>QInstaller::IntroductionPage</name>
    ...
    <message>
        <source>Quit</source>
        <translation>Beenden</translation>
    </message>
```

to

```
<context>
    <name>QInstaller::IntroductionPage</name>
    ...
    <message>
        <source>&amp;Quit</source>
        <translation>Beenden</translation>
    </message>
```

and recompiling the Framework leads to a translated Quit button (Beenden) within the framework.

I did not tried, but studying `/installer-framework/src/libs/installer/packagemanagergui.cpp` should enable you to translate the Next button, too.

[image]

Comment: Do I need to load the qm file through a C++ code? Or I don't need to code. Is it possible to load the qm file without C++ code?

Comment: I checked and added some additional information within the original answer.

Comment: The value of the button Next is "&amp;Next &gt;" or "&amp;Next"

Comment: Usefull information, could you post this info to Qt bugtracker?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a context may help:

```
function Component()
{
  qsTranslate("QInstaller::IntroductionPage", "&Quit");
}
```

It woked after Next and Back, but could not find where to write the `qsTranslate()`.